# Spark error when convert JavaRDD to DataFrame: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is not a valid external type for schema of array<string>

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.1.0. For the following code, which read a text file and convert the content to DataFrame, then feed into a Word2Vector model:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("word2vector").getOrCreate();
JavaRDD<String> lines = spark.sparkContext().textFile("input.txt", 10).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<List<String>> lists = lines.map(new Function<String, List<String>>(){
                public List<String> call(String line){
                    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
                    return list;
                }
            });

JavaRDD<Row> rows = lists.map(new Function<List<String>, Row>() {
                public Row call(List<String> list) {
                    return RowFactory.create(list);
                }
            });


StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                        new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty()) 
                    });

Dataset<Row> input = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
input.show(3);
Word2Vec word2Vec = new Word2Vec().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("result").setVectorSize(100).setMinCount(0);
Word2VecModel model = word2Vec.fit(input);
Dataset<Row> result = model.transform(input);
```

It throws an exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is not a valid external type for
>   schema of array

which happens at line `input.show(3)` , so the `createDataFrame()` is causing the exception because `Arrays.asList()` returns an **Arrays$ArrayList** which is not supported here. However the Spark Official Documentation has the following code:

```
List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Logistic regression models are neat".split(" ")))
    );

StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
      new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty())
});
Dataset<Row> documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
```

which works just fine. If **Arrays$ArrayList** is not supported, how come this code is working? The difference is I am converting a `JavaRDD<Row>` to DataFrame but the official documentation is converting a `List<Row>` to DataFrame. I believe Spark Java API has an overloaded method createDataFrame() which takes a `JavaRDD<Row>` and convert it to a DataFrame based on the provided schema. I am so confused about why it is not working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue several days ago and the only way to solve this problem is the use an array of array. Why ? Here is the response:

An ArrayType is wrapper for Scala Arrays which correspond one-to-one to Java arrays. Java ArrayList is not mapped by default to Scala Array so that's why you get the exception:

> java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is not a valid external type for schema of array

Hence, passing directly a String[] sould have work:

```
RowFactory.create(line.split(" "))
```

But since **create** takes as input an Object list as a row may have a  columns list, the String[] get interpreted to a list of String columns. That's why a double array of String is required:

```
RowFactory.create(new String[][] {line.split(" ")})
```

However, still the mystery of constructing a DataFrame from a Java List of rows in the spark documentation. This is because the SparkSession.createDataFrame function version that takes as first parameter java.util.List of rows makes special type checks and converts so that it converts all Java Iterable (so ArrayList) to a Scala Array.
However, the SparkSession.createDataFrame that takes JavaRDD maps directly the row content to the DataFrame.

To wrap-up, this is the correct version:

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Word2Vec").getOrCreate();
    SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN");
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("input.txt", 10).toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<Row> rows = lines.map(new Function<String, Row>(){
        public Row call(String line){
            return RowFactory.create(new String[][] {line.split(" ")});
        }
    });

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty())
    });
    Dataset<Row> input = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
    input.show(3);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I get this exception now:  [Ljava.lang.String; is not a valid external type for schema of string. Do you have the same error?

Comment: No, here is the exact code in Gist:
https://gist.github.com/radcheb/cd3c597a6893615a5d15feb6bc462256

Comment: Really not getting "since create takes as input an Object list ... interpreted to a list of String columns". I am getting each cell value and I am adding it to `ArrayList<String>` one by one. How I am supposed to form `String[][]` instead of `ArrayList<String>`? I created `String[] vals` adding cell values to it one by one. Then created `String[1][] valsWrapped`. Then did `valsWrapped[0] = vals`. It gave me `[[Ljava.lang.String; is not a valid external type for schema of string`

Comment: Asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623475/in-apache-spark-converting-javarddrow-to-datasetrow-gives-exception-arrayl). Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as the error says. `ArrayList` is not the equivalent of Scala's array. You should use a normal array (i.e `String[]`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

for me below is working fine

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRdd = rdd.map(r -> RowFactory.create(r.split(",")));
```