# xxx is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I try to use the sparksession createDataframe function and I keep getting the error like. xxx  is not a valid external type for schema of string. xxx can be Arrays$ArrayList and Ljava.lang.String.

This is the code of creating row

```
Row row = RowFactory.create(new String[][] {s.split(",")});
```

I make the schema like this

```
List<StructField> structfields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
for(ColumnMetaData c : metadata){
            System.out.println(c.getColumnName());
            structfields.add(DataTypes.createStructField( c.getColumnName(), DataTypes.StringType, false ));

        }

        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(structfields);
```

And I create the dataset

```
JavaRDD<Row> rdd = sc.parallelize(all_rows);
Dataset<Row> new_ds = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema);
```

I did reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567333/spark-error-when-convert-javardd-to-dataframe-java-util-arraysarraylist-is-not), but it seems like the answer doesn't work for me.

Also there is the log from spark

```
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, l_linestatus), StringType), true) AS l_linestatus#469
+- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, l_linestatus), StringType), true)
   +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, l_linestatus), StringType)
      +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, l_linestatus)
         +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
            +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
```