# In Apache Spark, converting JavaRDD<Row> to Dataset<Row> gives exception: ArrayList is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I am using [hbase-spark connector](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-spark) to fetch hbase data into spark `JavaRDD<Row>` (which I feel I able to do successfully since I am able to print the hbase data that is fetched). Then, I am trying to convert that `JavaRDD<Row>` to `Dataset<Row>`. But it gives me error which is given further in the post. First let me start how my code looks like.

```
private static JavaRDD<Row> loadHBaseRDD() throws ParseException
{
    //form list of row keys
    List<byte[]> rowKeys = new ArrayList<byte[]>(5);
    //consider ids is class level variable
    ids.forEach(id -> {
        rowKeys.add(Bytes.toBytes(id));     
    });
    JavaRDD<byte[]> rdd = jsc.parallelize(rowKeys);

    //make hbase-spark connector call 
    JavaRDD resultJRDD = jhbc.bulkGet(TableName.valueOf("table1"),2,rdd,new GetFunction(),new ResultFunction());

    return resultJRDD;
}
```

Notice that `bulkGet()` accepts instances `GetFunction` and `RsultFunction` classes. `GetFunction` class has single method which returns instance of `Get` class (from [hbase client](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Get.html)):

```
public static class GetFunction implements Function<byte[], Get> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Get call(byte[] v) throws Exception {
        return new Get(v);
    }
}
```

The `ResultFunction` has a function which converts instance of `Result` (hbase client class) to `Row`:

```
public static class ResultFunction implements Function<Result, Row> 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Row call(Result result) throws Exception 
    {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(); //notice this is arraylist, we talk about this latter

        for (Cell cell : result.rawCells()) {
            values.add(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell)));
        }
        return RowFactory.create(values);
    }
}
```

When I call `loadHBaseRDD()` and print the returned value, it prints the values correctly:

```
JavaRDD<Row> hbaseJavaRDD = loadHBaseRDD();
hbaseJavaRDD.foreach(row -> { 
    System.out.println(row);   //this prints rows correctly
});
```

It means rows have been correctly fetched from hbase to spark.
Now I want to convert `JavaRDD<Row>` to `Dataset<Row>` as explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema). Thus I first create `StructType`:

```
StructType schema = //create schema
```

Then I try converting `JavaRDD` to dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> hbaseDataFrame = sparksession1.createDataFrame(hbaseJavaRDD, schema);
hbaseDataFrame.show(false);
```

This throws exception with very big stacktrace (only part of which is shown below) occurring at line `hbaseDataFrame.show(false)` with first line as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.ArrayList is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

It seems that, because `values` is of type `ArrayList` inside `ResultFunction.call()`, it is giving exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.ArrayList is not a valid external type for schema of string`.

There is [similar question] on stackoveflow which has [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585010/1317018) saying that instead of list, one should return `String[][]`. Though I dont get the reasoning behind returning `String[][]`, I modified `ResultFunction` to have `values` of type `String[][]`:

```
public static class ResultFunction implements Function<Result, Row> 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Row call(Result result) throws Exception 
    {
        String[] values = new String[result.rawCells().length];
        String[][] valuesWrapped = new String[1][]; 

        for(int i=0;i<result.rawCells().length;i++)
        {
            values[i] = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(result.rawCells()[i]));
        }
        valuesWrapped[0] = values;
        return RowFactory.create(valuesWrapped);
    }
}
```

It gives below exception at same line `hbaseDataFrame.show(false)`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: [[Ljava.lang.String; is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

Finally I modified `ResultFunction` class again to have `values` variable of type `String[]`:

```
public static class ResultFunction implements Function<Result, Row>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Row call(Result result) throws Exception 
    {
        String[] values = new String[result.rawCells().length];     
        for(int i=0;i<result.rawCells().length;i++)
        {
            values[i] = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(result.rawCells()[i]));
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

And this is giving me exception with big stack trace having starting line:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
```

So what might be going wrong here? And how I am supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The last approach (of returning `String[] values`) was correct. The issues was with ill formed schema. It seems that I somehow ended up having one more column in the schema than is present in the data. (Thanks to the extra space character in the schema string containing columns separated by the single space. Extra space was creating extra column.)